# HomeKit accessoryDidUpdateServices not called

Tags: swift, homekit

In the following quick and dirty test app, I am trying to receive light level updates from a Hue motion detector accessory using accessoryDidUpdateServices(). However the delegate function is never called. I'm running it on an iPhone with iOS 12.1.4 installed.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong, and what I need to do to properly handle HMService updates?

```
import HomeKit

public class ViewController: UIViewController, HMHomeManagerDelegate, HMAccessoryDelegate {

    var manager: HMHomeManager!

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = HMHomeManager()
        manager.delegate = self
    }

    public func homeManagerDidUpdateHomes(_ manager: HMHomeManager) {
        let service = manager.primaryHome!.servicesWithTypes([HMServiceTypeLightSensor])!.first!
        service.accessory!.delegate = self
        let characteristic = service.characteristics.filter({ $0.characteristicType == HMCharacteristicTypeCurrentLightLevel }).first!

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
            print("Light level: \(characteristic.value!)")
        }
    }

    public func accessoryDidUpdateServices(_ accessory: HMAccessory) {
        print("Service updated: \(accessory.name)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using accessoryDidUpdateService when I should have used accessory:didUpdateValueFor. With the latter func in place, the code runs as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a `addHomes(manager.homes)` inside your `viewDidLoad` and you need to make sure you create a new home to add it to and then you can add accessories and add to a home.

I highly recommend this HomeKit tutorial on the RayWenderlich website: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5313-homekit-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: The addHomes() call is not necessary in this instance because I am querying against a live Hue Bridge/HomeKit that has already been configured. But thanks for the link: I ultimately found my answer buried at the bottom.